# How to strike through obliquely with css

Tags: html, css, image, strikethrough

I need something like this:
[image]

How can achieve this with css? I know that one way is use background image, but can I achieve this only with css without any image?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

There is a hacky way to do this, using the `:before` pseudo element. You give the `:before` a border, then rotate it with a CSS transform. Doing it this way adds no extra elements to the DOM, and adding/removing the strikethrough is a simple as adding/removing the class.

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/oqibus/1/)

#### Caveats

- This will only work down to IE8. IE7 [does not support `:before`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent), however will degrade gracefully in browsers that *do* support `:before` but don't support CSS transforms.
- The angle of rotation is fixed. If the text is longer, the line will not touch the corners of the text. Be mindful of this.

#### CSS

```css
.strikethrough {
  position: relative;
}
.strikethrough:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
}
```

#### HTML

```
<span class="strikethrough">Deleted text</span>
```

Comment: I don't think that this works in IE8 .. it doesn't have any analog to `transform` that I know of unless it can work with `filter`

Comment: You're right, sorry. IE8 will degrade gracefully into a normal strikethrough line. I should have made that clear

Comment: Hi @Bojangles, I'm trying to apply this to a TD element, but it seems to go a bit wrong in Firefox.. http://jsfiddle.net/Ms4Qy/  Any idea why this might be? Thanks

Comment: Post a new question instead of putting your problem in a comment to this answer

Comment: Sure - done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945031/css-strikethrough-effect-firefox-issue

Comment: Another caveat to consider — the strikethrough won't render as expected if your text breaks onto two lines: http://d.pr/i/1dKP5

Answer (score 93):

You can use background `linear-gradient` with `currentColor` to avoid hardcoding font color:

```css
.strikediag {
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 47.75%, currentColor 49.5%, currentColor 50.5%, transparent 52.25%);
}
.withpadding {
  padding: 0 0.15em;
}
```

```html
The value is <span class="strikediag">2x</span> 3x<br>
The number is <span class="strikediag">1234567890</span>.
<p>
The value is <span class="strikediag withpadding">2x</span>3x<br>
The number is <span class="strikediag withpadding">1234567890</span>.
```

If you don't need the element to be fully inline, you can use a pseudo element to place the line on top of the element. This way the angle can be adjusted by changing the pseudo element's size:

```css
.strikediag {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.strikediag::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.1em;
  right: -0.1em;
  top: 0.38em;
  bottom: 0.38em;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 45.5%, currentColor 47.5%, currentColor 52.5%, transparent 54.5%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
The value is <span class="strikediag">2x</span> 3x<br>
The number is <span class="strikediag">1234567890</span>.
```

Answer (score 7):

```css
del {
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
}
del::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:0; width:100%; height:1px; 
  background:black;
  transform:rotate(-7deg);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you could probably apply a rotation effect to a horizontal rule.  Something like:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <hr />
    123456
  </body>
</html>
```

With the CSS:

```css
hr
{
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #000000;
  border-color: #000000;
  transform:rotate(-7deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-7deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-7deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-7deg);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmQ9T/1/)

Your mileage may vary depending on browser and version though, so I'm not sure if I'd resort to this.  You might have to pull off some funky VML code to support older versions of IE, for example.

Comment: Note 1: `-7` degrees, not `+7`; note 2: `HR` is gray in Chrome; is that possible to override?

Comment: And what about all the browsers that don't support CSS3 transforms?

Comment: Yup, I believe you'll need to set `border-color` and `background-color`.  [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmQ9T/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Enhancing Bojangles answer from above:

```
.strike-diagonal-price {
position: relative;
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
.strike-diagonal-price:before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
left: 0;
top: 45%;
right: 0;
border-top: 2px solid;
border-color: red;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-25deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-25deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-25deg);
transform: rotate(-25deg);
}
```

Now I get the affect I needed:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 gradient

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(234,20,136) 0%, rgb(255,46,164) 50%, rgb(255,74,197) 0%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(234,20,136) 0%, rgb(255,46,164) 50%, rgb(255,74,197) 0%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(234,20,136) 0%, rgb(255,46,164) 50%, rgb(255,74,197) 0%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(234,20,136) 0%, rgb(255,46,164) 50%, rgb(255,74,197) 0%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(234,20,136) 0%, rgb(255,46,164) 50%, rgb(255,74,197) 0%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom,right top,color-stop(0, rgb(234,20,136)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(255,46,164)), color-stop(0, rgb(255,74,197)) );
```

My example won't fill your needs perfectly but, for more info and funny tweaks, see http://gradients.glrzad.com/.

What you have to do is create a `background-gradient` of `white-black-white` and position your `opacity` at something like `48% 50% 52%`.

Comment: this gives me blocks, not lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using clip-path, which is responsive also

```css
p{
  position : relative
}
span{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color : black;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0 , 100% 12% ,0% 100% , 0% 88%);
}
```

```html
<p><span/>$100</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a sustainable css solution to this.

My pure CSS solution would be to place another element of text behind your first element of text that  is identical in number of characters (characters being ' '), a text-decleration of line-through, and a transform of rotate.

Something like:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .strike{
       text-decoration: line-through;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(344deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(344deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(344deg);}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Text to display</p>
    <p class='strike'></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Text Rotation example](http://www.css3maker.com/text-rotation.html)

I am looking forward to seeing better answers from other users.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but as an alternative you can use CSS3 Linear Gradients for example (http://codepen.io/yusuf-azer/pen/ojJLoG).

For extensive explaining and a LESS Solution check

http://www.yusufazer.com/tutorials-how-to/how-to-make-a-diagonal-line-through-with-css3/

```
span.price--line-through {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 19.1% -7.9%, 81% 107.9%, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(.475, #fff), color-stop(.5, #000), color-stop(.515, #fff), color-stop(1, #fff));
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(287deg, #fff 0%, #fff 47.5%, #000 50%, #fff 51.5%, #fff 100%);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(163deg, #fff 0%, #fff 47.5%, #000 50%, #fff 51.5%, #fff 100%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(287deg, #fff 0%, #fff 47.5%, #000 50%, #fff 51.5%, #fff 100%);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it this way using an SVG in the HTM with a CSS class:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Regular Price: <div class="zIndex-10a">$4.50</div><div class="zIndex-10b"><svg height="16" width="5"><line x1="0" y1="20" x2="40" y2="0" class="Strike-01a"></svg></div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* -- CONTAINS TEXT TO STRIKE ---- */ .zIndex-10a { display: inline-block; position: relative;  left:  0px; z-index: 10; }
/* -- CONTAINS SVG LINE IN HTML -- */ .zIndex-10b { display: inline-block; position: relative; right: 40px; z-index: 11; }
/* -- SVG STROKE PROPERTIES ------ */ .Strike-01a { stroke: rgb(255,0,0); stroke-width:2; }
```

There might be simpler easier ways by now. I just cooked this up in a pinch for my product detail special offer page. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: There must be something missing because this **doesn't work** in a snippet as-is

Answer (score -1):

Try

```css
.mydiv {
    background-color: #990000;
    color: #FFFF00;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
.strikethrough-100p, .strikethrough-50p{
  position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.strikethrough-100p:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid;
  border-color: inherit;

  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
}
.strikethrough-50p:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width:50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid;
  border-color: inherit;

  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
<div class="strikethrough-100p">123456</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="mydiv">
<div class="strikethrough-50p">123456</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

And here's a fancy version:

```
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-border-radius:20px 0;
-webkit-border-radius:20px 0;
border-radius:20px 0;
content: "";
height:5px; left:-5%;
position:absolute;
top:30%;
-moz-transform:rotate(-7deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg);
transform:rotate(-7deg);
transform-origin:50% 50% 0;
width:110%;
```