# CSS diagonal lines - how to fit into its parent element?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, diagonal

How can I make a diagonal line fill in and fit into a box (just pure css - without any use of background image)?

```css
div.diagonal-container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.to-right,
.to-left {
    border-top:1px solid #ff00ff;
    width:100%;

    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.to-right {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal-container" style="">
    <div class="to-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="diagonal-container" style="">
    <div class="to-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="diagonal-container" style="">
    <div class="to-left"></div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf9e878v/).

Also, is it possible to have an element only without wrapping it? For instance:

```
<div class="to-right"></div>
<div class="to-right"></div>
<div class="to-left"></div>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602291/diagonal-line-through-div-or-span

Comment: i dont want to use a background image - just pure css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw the lines with pseudo elements.

```css
.diagonal-container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.diagonal-container:before {
  border-top: 1px solid #ff00ff;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: -50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.to-right:before {
  right: 0; left: -50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal-container to-right">
</div>

<div class="diagonal-container to-left">
</div>

<div class="diagonal-container to-right">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add a `linear-gradient` `background` and ditch the inner element, add that class to the other div

```css
div.diagonal-container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.to-right {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent calc(50% - 1px), red 50%, transparent calc(50% + 1px) );
}

.to-left {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent calc(50% - 1px), red 50%, transparent calc(50% + 1px) );
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal-container to-right"></div>

<div class="diagonal-container to-right"></div>

<div class="diagonal-container to-left"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

1. Use `position: relative` to the container and `position: absolute` for the lines.
2. Use `transform-origin: left` and `left: 0` for the left line, `transform-origin: right` and `right: 0` for the right line.
3. If `width` and `height` of the container are equal, then the width of the line'll be ~`141.5%`.

```css
.diagonal-container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.to-right, .to-left {
    border-top: 1px solid #ff00ff;
    width: 141.5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.to-left {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    -ms-transform-origin: left;
    transform-origin: left;
    left: 0;
}

.to-right {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right;
    -ms-transform-origin: right;
    transform-origin: right;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal-container">
    <div class="to-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="diagonal-container">
    <div class="to-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="diagonal-container">
    <div class="to-left"></div>
</div>
```

If you used a CSS preprocessor ([LESS](http://lesscss.org) for example), you'd do something like this:

```
@width: 400px;
@height: 400px;

.rotate(@angle, @origin) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(@angle);
    -ms-transform: rotate(@angle);
    transform: rotate(@angle);
    -webkit-transform-origin: @origin;
    -ms-transform-origin: @origin;
    transform-origin: @origin;
}

.diagonal-container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: @width;
    height: @width;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.to-right, .to-left {
    border-top: 1px solid #ff00ff;
    width: sqrt(@width*@width + @height*@height);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.to-left {
    .rotate(45deg, left);
    left: 0;
}

.to-right {
    .rotate(-45deg, right);
    right: 0;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/VPoZoO?editors=1100#0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your css:

```
div.diagonal-container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.to-right,
.to-left {
  border-top: 1px solid #ff00ff;
  width: 100%;
}

.to-left {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
    transform-origin: top left;
}

.to-right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

Comment: The other answer is better than mine, op ;)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use SVG, which gives nice responsive diagonal lines, works on almost all browsers.

```css
.box {
    width: 20rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 70%, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.svg-stroke {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <svg class='svg-stroke' viewBox='0 0 10 10' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
         <line x1='10' y1='0' x2='0' y2='10' stroke='red' stroke-width='.2' stroke-opacity='0.2' />
    </svg>
</div>
```