# CSS strikethrough effect, Firefox issue

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to use the CSS strikethrough effect described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14593540/62072 with a TD element, but it seems to go a bit wrong in Firefox..

**Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

**CSS**

```css
.strikethrough
{
    position: relative;
}

    .strikethrough:before
    {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        /*width: 170%;*/
        /*left: -35%;*/
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #333333;
        /*border-color: inherit;*/
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-35deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-35deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-35deg);
        transform: rotate(-35deg);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="strikethrough">
    Test
</span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="strikethrough">
            5
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Ms4Qy/

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: You should explain what “a bit wrong” means.

Comment: Fair point @JukkaK.Korpela, I've added some screenshots which should hopefully illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FF is known to have some strange behaviors with absolute elements inside element with display of `table-cell`.

The following setting might do the work (but it might cause some other problems with the table cells):

```
.strikethrough
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Ms4Qy/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Itay. Unfortunately the `inline-block` style did cause other problems with the table cells, so I ended up just putting `<span>` elements in the table cells and applying the style to them.

Comment: @TomHunter What you've written is a very common solution for such cases (unfortunately).