# How to strike through obliquely with css showing the text on top of the strike through

Tags: css

I've just run into a very nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593415/how-to-strike-through-obliquely-with-css) about "How to strike through obliquely with css". The solution is nice, but I wonder if it is possible to pimp the CSS snippet there to show the text on top of the strike through.

If not, an alternate solution?

Comment: the confusing thing is even if the strike lays on top but if both the strike and the text have the same color, it won't help us see that. So we need to specify different colors for the text and the strike.

Comment: Of course, I meant to write a white text on top of a red 3px thick line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move something behind the other you need to give it a `z-index` that is lower than the other element, in this case I gave the strike a `z-index` of -1

http://jsfiddle.net/p2F7G/1/

```
.strikethrough {
  position: relative;
}
.strikethrough:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-color: #F00;
  z-index: -1;

  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But I don't get why... I mean the text is part of the same span element, so I thought z-index was applied to the line and to the text. Why the text doesn't change layer too?

Comment: because you are not applying it to the .strikethrough text, you're applying it to the css element before the text.

have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/p2F7G/3/ that may explain it.

Comment: Let me know if that helped explain it, if not I can probably make some better examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the strikethru a lower `z-index` than the text. I highlighted the text red so it can be seen:

```
.strikethrough {
  position: relative;
  color: #f00;
}
.strikethrough:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000;

  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/oqibus/109/