# Is it possible to cross out cells in an HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create an HTML table in which I am able to cross out cells as shown in the following drawing:

[image: Table with crossed out cells]

I originally thought about doing a CSS right triangle in the cell, but I couldn't figure out how to color just the hypotenuse and not the other two sides or the triangle itself.

In other words, is what I want to do possible?
Would making an image with a diagonal line and then making that image stretch 100% the width and height of the cell make the most sense?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602291/diagonal-line-through-div-or-span

Comment: You could add a class with a background image.

Comment: JavaScript solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127035/how-to-create-a-diagonal-line-within-a-table-cell

Comment: CSS alone solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593415/how-to-strike-through-obliquely-with-css

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, this is a bit hacky, but it works.
Utilize [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients)

### Using `background-image` for the current cell, strike through under content

```css
table
{
  min-width: 100%;
}

table td
{
  border: 1px solid silver;
  position: relative;
}

table td.crossed
{
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,  transparent calc(50% - 1px), red, transparent calc(50% + 1px)); 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td class="crossed">Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Strike through table cell content using pseudo-element

If you want the strike through the content of the cell, you may also use pseudo elements, like this:

```css
table
{
  min-width: 100%;
}

table td
{
  border: 1px solid silver;
  position: relative;
}

table td.crossed::after
{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,  transparent calc(50% - 1px), red, transparent calc(50% + 1px)); 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td class="crossed">Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Please keep in mind that IE8 and IE9 won't be able to display these gradients. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Comment: @Damien thanks for your comment. You are right. If these browsers are in the list of requirements, you will have to prepare a fallback solution, maybe using static images or other solutions that have been linked.

Comment: This solution does not works for oldest browser versions... I am trying to find a solution to do this in IE8 (but is not easly)

Comment: With some sizes I saw a little part of a line at the bottom right corner. Adding `background-repeat: no-repeat;` fixed the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to use linear-gradient over multiple `tr`s in a column?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style>
td.diagonalRising
{
   background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff     
   49.9%,#000000 50%,#000000 51%,#ffffff 51.1%,#ffffff 100%);
}

td.diagonalFalling
{
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #fff 0%,#fff 49.9%,#000000    
 50%,#000000 51%,#fff 51.1%,#fff 100%);
}
<style>
```

The above link will explain you further. It also support all directions, vertical, horizontal or diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simply `backgroundImage: 'linear(to bottom right, black)'`
(in react style property) ??